Is it possible to override standard onnxruntime operators in C++ with runtime registration?
Referencing the onnxruntime documentation on custom operators ( https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/reference/operators/add-custom-op.html ), it's not clear to me whether:
(A) Custom operators can be registered at runtime, or whether they have to be compiled into the onnxruntime library itself;
(B) Can custom operators override built-in operators in this way. The docs say that custom operators CAN override built-in operators, but no example is provided, and nor is it clear whether there is a runtime path for this.
If anyone has experience with this I would love your guidance!
